# Replacement compiler for Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I like Qt Creator as an IDE, but the built-in compiler is slower than dirt.

Can I replace it, and if so, with what?

Developing on Windows but targeting multiple Mac as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default on Windows the compiler is mingw, a port of GCC. Qt also contains support for the Visual Studio compilers, which you can switch to.

The only full-fledged C++ compiler on Macintosh is GCC.

C++, especially with template heavy code, is *slow* to compile. There is no avoiding this. In my experience, Visual Studio is not appreciably faster on complex code bases over GCC.

Comment: clang is a viable option for C and Obj-C on the Mac, but C++ support is still not quite ready for prime-time yet.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of compiler depends on your toolchain (if you use qmake or cmake) plus your platform (e.g. cl is only available on Windows).

I don't think you can choose arbitrary compilers (e.g. Sun CC, Intel) and QtCreator will correctly picks up the compiling error messages. GCC is still the best supported compiler to use with QtCreator.

Perhaps a solution for you will be to pass -j8 as an extra build flag. Check the Projects pane.